# I'm trying to make use of the service worker in create-react-app but I keep getting...wont register sw. Current env: development

Tags: reactjs, service-worker

I'm using create-react-app but the service worker isnt working. Im using localhost

I'm trying to make this a PWA, i'm using the stock manifest file and service worker generated when you create-react-app, i've also rand npm run-script build and got the generated service-worker.js file. The problem is that I keep getting this in the console. **wont register sw. Current env: development** help?

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
   const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;

   if (isLocalhost) {
    // This is running on localhost. Let's check if a service worker 
       still exists or not.
        checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config);

    // Add some additional logging to localhost, pointing developers to 
      the
    // service worker/PWA documentation.
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(() => {
          console.log(
            "This web app is being served cache-first by a service " +
              "worker. To learn more"
          );
        });
      } else {
        // Is not localhost. Just register service worker
        registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.log("wont register sw. Current env:", process.env.NODE_ENV);
  }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you are running through https otherwise it won't work. https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/#you_need_https

Comment: @TalgatSaribayev On localhost we don't need to have https for service worker to work.

Comment: It looks like you're missing some code in your question. You have a trailing `else` statement, and it's likely that the missing code is where your issue is hidden. CRA won't register the service worker unless the application is running in production mode. I think the `if` condition should look something like `environment.name === 'production'`, and by removing that you should be able to solve your issue.

Comment: suggested workaround - deploy a production build to a local static server:

`npm run build && npx serve -s build`

Answer (score 3):

Here are the steps:

**Step 1:**
A new JavaScript file: **svcWorker.js** needs to be created in the **public** folder. Add the following code in it:

```
var CACHE_NAME = 'task-manager-pwa';
var urlsToCache = [
  '/',
  '/completed'
];

// Install service worker
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
  // Perform the install steps
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
      .then(function(cache) {
        console.log('Cache opened');
        return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
      })
  );
});

// Cache and return the requests
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request)
      .then(function(response) {
        // Return response as Cache is hit 
        if (response) {
          return response;
        }
        return fetch(event.request);
      }
    )
  );
});

// Update service worker
self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
  var cacheWhitelist = ['task-manager-pwa'];
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(cacheNames => {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.map(cacheName => {
          if (cacheWhitelist.indexOf(cacheName) === -1) {
            return caches.delete(cacheName);
          }
        })
      );
    })
  );
});
```

**Step 2:**
Make changes to the index.html file to check if the client browser supports service workers and also the application renders styling and works fine without any trace of JavaScript loading. Code for this is added between the `<style> </style>` and `<body> </body>` tags. Here is the full code in index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"
    />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="logo512.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>React PWA App</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: sans-serif;
      }
      .navbar {
        background-color: #4169e1;
      }
      .navbar h3 {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 10px;
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      .navbar a {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      .page-info {
        padding: 10px;
      }
      .Current {
        color: #2e8b57;
      }
      .Completed {
        color: #ff6347;
        text-decoration: line-through;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>Enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root">
      <div class="navbar">
        <h3>Task Manager</h3>
        <a href="/">Present Tasks</a>
        <a href="/completed">Finished Tasks</a>
      </div>
      <p class="page-info">
        App Loading...
      </p>
    </div>
    <script>
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
          navigator.serviceWorker.register('svcWorker.js').then(function(registration) {
            console.log('Worker registration is successful', registration.scope);
          }, function(err) {
            console.log('Worker registration has failed', err);
          }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
          });
        });
      } else {
        console.log('Service Worker is not supported by your browser.');
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Step 3:**
In index.js, make sure that you use: `serviceWorker.register()`
Here is code in **index.js**:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
serviceWorker.register();
```

I have written all these steps and other steps to create a Simple React PWA App in my blog post with working code in GitHub. Please refer to: http://softwaredevelopercentral.blogspot.com/2019/10/react-pwa-tutorial.html

Answer (score 3):

Main think you need to know: Create the servieWorker inside public folder in order to be treated as .js file and not text/html file.

Then register that service in  your index.js

Step 1, create **public/sw.js**

```
self.addEventListener('message', async (event) => {
  console.log('Got message in the service worker', event);
});
```

Step 2, create **src/sw-register.js**

```
export default function LocalServiceWorkerRegister() {
  const swPath = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/sw-build.js`;
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register(swPath).then(registration => {
        console.log('Service worker registered');
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Step 3, in **src/index.js**, add these two lines

```
import LocalServiceWorkerRegister from './sw-register';
...
LocalServiceWorkerRegister();
```

You can change some things for your needs, but with those changes, you should be able to work with a custom service worker in a create-react-app application

Comment: Is it possible to have your service-worker code in the src folder and not public? How would one do that?