# ServiceWorker MIME Type Error ('text/html') on register (React)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, service-worker

#### The current behavior:

Service worker does not register due to the below error

#### The expected behavior:

Service worker registers

---

#### Details

Posted as a github issue:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8593

Service worker is giving the following error when attempting to register:

> Error during service worker registration:
>   DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:3000/') with script ('http://localhost:3000/sw.js'):
>   The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').
>   console. @ index.js:1

`sw.js` is showing in the sources tab of the Chrome dev tools, but not registering.

React version: 16.12.0

Error Message:

> Error during service worker registration: DOMException:
>   Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:3000/') with script ('http://localhost:3000/sw.js'):
>   The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').

Failed ServiceWorker in Chrome's Inspect Tab:
[image: Chrome Error]

---

#### Steps To Reproduce:

Register a Service Worker in React (change from unregister to register, or place SW code directly in index.html, or use a simpler SW. All cause the same error when running, in either dev or a build react app.)

SW Example:

```
export function register() {
  if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker
      .register("./sw.js")
      .then(function(registration) {
        // Successful registration
        console.log(
          "Hooray. Registration successful, scope is:",
          registration.scope
        );
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        // Failed registration, service worker won’t be installed
        console.log(
          "Whoops. Service worker registration failed, error:",
          error
        );
      });
  }
}
```

---

#### Also, `http://localhost:3000/sw.js when using the default SW from React returns this HTML:

[image]

#### Using the code sample above returns index.html (default 404, http://localhost:3000/) when trying to access http://localhost:3000/sw.js

---

#### Suggested fixes:

Move `sw.js` to public folder, gives this error:
[image: Public folder error]

---

Is there a way to change the header (from `text/html` to `application/javascript`) for specifically `sw.js` when served to the browser in React?

I tried following some Medium articles on registering custom serviceWorkers in React, to no avail...

Comment: how are you serving `sw.js`?

Comment: Using serviceWorker.register() from React.

Comment: I’m saying on your web server

Comment: I'm just using the basic npm start, whichever that uses for React's default. Currently in development so haven't deployed. I've also done npm build, then serve -s build to serve the built project, but it still has the same error.

Comment: suggested workaround - deploy a production build to a local static server:

`npm run build && npx serve -s build`

Answer (score 10):

When running webpack dev server, it renders default index.html for missing resource.

If you use your browser to load `http://localhost:3000/sw.js`, you will actually see a rendered react app (started by the index.html). That's why the mime type is html, not javascript.

This fallback to index.html is designed to support SPA with front-end routes. For example `/product/123/reviews` has no such html file in backend, the JS SPA app takes care of it in front-end.

Why your file is missing? I guess you created that file in the root folder of your project.

**Webpack dev server doesn't serve from that root folder.**

Move your `sw.js` into `public/` folder of your project, it will be served up as expected.

Comment: Also better to change `.register("./sw.js")` to `.register("/sw.js")` to avoid current route.

Comment: `http://localhost:3000/sw.js` responds with the code wrapped in html, and placing sw.js returns an error

ERRORS:
Example localhost/sw.js:
https://imgur.com/a/EjKg8RJ 
||
Error from placing in public:
https://imgur.com/a/xdf772U

Comment: The sw.js is in the same spot as the default serviceWorker.js file that is bundled with create-react-app

Comment: Changing `'./sw.js'` to `/sw.js` gives this error: Module not found: You attempted to import /sw which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.

Comment: Update: Changing back to the code sample for the SW as above, returns index.html. However, moving to the public folder returns the error as above.

Comment: That `src/serviceWorker.js` is not the service worker js file itself. It is to load `swUrl` which is pointed to `/service-worker.js`. The `/service-worker.js` is supplied by react-scripts. Once you run `npm run build`, you can see the content of it in `static/` folder.

Comment: If you want to make your own `/sw.js` file, you can modify `src/serviceWorker.js` `swUrl` to your file I think.
You cannot do `import "../public/sw.js";` in any of your source code, because `sw.js` will be loaded by `navigator.serviceWorker.register(...)`, not by js import.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209129/discussion-between-sean-moody-and-huocp).

Comment: @SeanMoody huocp did you find a solution for this? I need to upload huge files, I need this custom service worker to upload them without blocking the UI. Pls let me know if you came up with a solution, I got the same errors as SeanMoody

Comment: @Jhonatan I'm sorry I've moved on with the project and I cannot remember at the moment. I think it was something to do with the Express Server/Proxy on the dev side of the build. I got it working though when it builds out to Heroku with the ServiceWorker file included in the create-react-app. I scrapped the ServiceWorker included here and just used the one included without modifications. If I remember what it was I'll update this comment...

Comment: @SeanMoody I got it, you actually gave the answer. Move to  public folder, and then importing the SW as if my index.js was already there. Thank you!

Comment: @Jhonatan No problem, glad you got it fixed!

Answer (score 3):

This may be a duplicate of this one [61776698](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57838179/im-trying-to-make-use-of-the-service-worker-in-create-react-app-but-i-keep-gett/61776698#61776698)

Main thing you need to know: Create the serviceWorker inside public folder in order to be treated as .js file and not text/html file.

Then register that service in  your index.js

Step 1, create **public/sw.js**

```
self.addEventListener('message', async (event) => {
  console.log('Got message in the service worker', event);
});
```

Step 2, create **src/sw-register.js**

```
export default function LocalServiceWorkerRegister() {
  const swPath = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/sw-build.js`;
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register(swPath).then(registration => {
        console.log('Service worker registered');
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Step 3, in **src/index.js**, add these two lines

```
import LocalServiceWorkerRegister from './sw-register';
...
LocalServiceWorkerRegister();
```

You can change some things for your needs, but with those changes, you should be able to work with a custom service worker in a create-react-app application

Comment: the path is different than the file name (`sw-build.js` / `sw.js`). is this intentional?

Comment: Care to explain how this answer relates to the unsupported mime-type question?

Answer (score 0):

You can write code at server side to handle sw.js file. below is nodejs code which intercept sw.js file request and read from folder and send back to browser.

```
app.get('/sw.js', (req, res) => {
  if (__DEVELOPMENT__) {
    http.get('http://localhost:4001/static/build/sw.js', (r) => {
      res.set({
        'Content-Type': 'text/javascript',
        'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'
      });
      r.setEncoding('utf8');
      r.pipe(res);
    }).on('error', (e) => {
      console.error(`Error in sending sw.js in dev mode : ${e.message}`);
    });
  } else {
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
    res.sendFile('sw.js', { root: path.join(__ROOT_DIRECTORY__, 'assets', 'build') }); // eslint-disable-line no-undef
  }
});
```