# Service Worker registration error (Unsupported mime type) with reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker

I'm trying to get acquainted with service worker, so I created a React project with create-react-app and activated service worker by replacing call to `unregister()` with `register()`

My index.js is currently :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Router, store } from './core';
import './index.css';
import { register } from './serviceWorkerRegistration';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router/>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

register();
```

My problem is an error I guet and I don't understand

> Error during service worker registration: DOMException: Failed to
> register a ServiceWorker for scope
> ('https://create-react-app.herokuapp.com/') with script
> ('https://create-react-app.herokuapp.com/service-worker.js'):
> The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').

Since the documentation explain that we should juste replace unregister with register, I don't understand why it is not working.

Comment: Hope this discussion will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60500779/serviceworker-mime-type-error-text-html-on-register-react

Comment: Indeed the discussion is partially helpful, thank you. However I don't understand why I've got the error message on one project but not on another one barelly different.